# Copy & Paste strings into a single column X times, one string at a time

Tags: excel, vba, dataset, copy-paste

I am trying to create an Excel dataset, and am looking for VBA code to do the following.  I already have the ID & Name columns, but need to copy/paste the State column like so:

| ID | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Homer Simpson | Arizona |
| 2 | Ned Flanders | Arizona |
| 3 | Barney Gumble | Arizona |
| 4 | Waylon Smithers | Arizona |
| 1 | Homer Simpson | Utah |
| 2 | Ned Flanders | Utah |
| 3 | Barney Gumble | Utah |
| 4 | Waylon Smithers | Utah |
| 1 | Homer Simpson | California |
| 2 | Ned Flanders | California |
| 3 | Barney Gumble | California |
| 4 | Waylon Smithers | California |
| 1 | Homer Simpson | New York |
| 2 | Ned Flanders | New York |
| 3 | Barney Gumble | New York |
| 4 | Waylon Smithers | New York |

I have the states on the same worksheet/tab as followed:

| State |
| --- |
| Arizona |
| Utah |
| California |
| New York |

Thank you.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it.  Looking for VBA code to do this.  Thanks

Comment: Do you specifically just want to copy things from one column to another, but insert each entry 4 times? Or is there any other conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in C2 and copy down

```
=IF(A2=1,INDEX($F$2:$F$17,COUNTIF($A$1:A2,1)),C1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  Works like a charm.  I tried =IF(A2=1,INDEX($F$2:$F$5,COUNTIF($A$1:A2,1)),C1) too, and works as well.  Genius :)

Comment: @HTMLHelpMe.. Glad to head that :) .. yes $F$2:$F$5 should work.. I just kept some additional room.